# How to make servlets for openshift tomcat?

Tags: tomcat, servlets, openshift

So I got all keys, tools for Eclipse, created new deafult applicaion, ok it shows [somepage](http://second-megatests.rhcloud.com/).

Then I change

> src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml

as it is told to in readme on:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>work</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>kea.webpro.WorkServlet</servlet-class>    
  </servlet>  
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>work</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/work</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And add some java-classes in

> src/main/java

And then I go [here](http://second-megatests.rhcloud.com/work) i get

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: kea.webpro.WorkServlet at first time and next times resource not found.

I guess my custom web.xml has been succesfully read. But my java class unfortunately not. So how to make simple servlet that generating some simple html-page with hello world on openshift tomcat?

At my local tomcat everything is fine, I generate whatever i want to. though my servlet structure is much more simple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the javax.servlet-api to your pom.xml file.  Check out this tutorial and it will help you out about what to add to your pom.xml and where.  Also, you can use Servlet 3.0 and use annotations instead of the old web.xml way.

https://www.openshift.com/forums/openshift/how-to-upload-and-serve-files-using-java-servlets-on-openshift

Comment: https://github.com/gssOpenShiftsupportExamples/Tomcat_Example may also provide an example.

Comment: This made me realize that I was suppose to use Annotations in specifying the servlet name and url pattern